# Java annotation processor Element AnnotationMirror for repeatable annotations

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

If I have an annotation `@Schedule` that is [repeatable](https://openjdk.org/jeps/120) as described [in the Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/repeating.html); and I call [`Element.getAnnotationMirrors()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/Element.html#getAnnotationMirrors()); will the list contain repeated annotations themselves (e.g. `@Schedule` in the tutorial), or will returned list contain their container annotation (e.g. `@Schedules` from the tutorial)?

Is the behavior different if a single occurrence or more than one occurrence of the repeatable annotation appears on the element?

Comment: Seems like you didn't find the answer in the documentation, so you are asking here. If so, then did you try some code for it? If yes, then what was the problem you faced? If not, then this question would have reason to be closed with "Needs debugging details" (IMO). By the way the documentation of method `getAnnotationMirrors` states that it returns the declaration annotations that are directly present on the `Element`. So you can start by finding out which annotations are considered *declaration* ones, which are considered *directly present* and if your annotation falls into these categories.

Comment: This information can then be found in the rest of the documentation that the method guides you to read, ie [the documentation of `AnnotatedConstruct`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/AnnotatedConstruct.html). By just reading that documentation I would personally expect that when you annotate an `Element` with a repeatable annotation then all (directly present) instances of it would appear in the returned list of the method (ie all the occurences of your repeatable annotation for that `Element`). No *container* annotations included in this case.